# How do I upcast route parameters for entity_revision?

Tags: routes, 9

My custom entity is revisionable. I can see revisions, but my revision revert form doesn't work. The route for the form is definited in *msul_rovi_games.routing.yml*.

```
entity.rovi_game.revision_revert_confirm:
  path: '/rovi_game/{rovi_game}/revisions/{rovi_game_revision}/revert'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Revert to an earlier revision'
    _form: '\Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Form\RoviGameRevisionRevertForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rovi_game entities'
    rovi_game: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    rovi_game:
      type: entity:rovi_game
    rovi_game_revision:
      type: entity_revision:rovi_game
```

The form is defined in *src/Form/RoviGameRevisionRevertForm.php*.

```
namespace Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Form;

use Drupal\Component\Datetime\TimeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\ConfirmFormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Entity\RoviGameInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Provides a form for reverting a rovi_game revision.
 *
 * @internal
 */
class RoviGameRevisionRevertForm extends ConfirmFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, RoviGameInterface $rovi_game_revision = NULL) {
    $this->revision = $rovi_game_revision;
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    return $form;
  }
}
```

When I attempt to revert, I get the following error.

> TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Form\RoviGameRevisionRevertForm::buildForm() must implement interface Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Entity\RoviGameInterface or be null, string given in Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Form\RoviGameRevisionRevertForm->buildForm() (line 116 of /opt/drupal/web/modules/custom/msul_rovi_games/src/Form/RoviGameRevisionRevertForm.php)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just missing a level, 'parameters', in your options array. See [Upcasting route slug name options](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/parameter-upcasting-in-routes#s-upcasting-route-slug-name-options). Note that parameters must be nested under *options > parameters*.

```
foobar.view:
  path: '/foobar/{foobar_placeholder}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\foobar\Controller\Foobar::content'
    _title: 'Oh yeah foobar'
  options:
    parameters:
      foobar_placeholder:
        type: entity:foobar
```

Your code updated:

```
entity.rovi_game.revision_revert_confirm:
  path: '/rovi_game/{rovi_game}/revisions/{rovi_game_revision}/revert'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Revert to an earlier revision'
    _form: '\Drupal\msul_rovi_games\Form\RoviGameRevisionRevertForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer rovi_game entities'
    rovi_game: \d+
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    # Nest parameters under "parameters"
    parameters:
      rovi_game:
        type: entity:rovi_game
      rovi_game_revision:
        type: entity_revision:rovi_game
```